# get value and reference object property by index

Tags: javascript, arrays

Object:

```
obj = {
    "expired":93,
    "old3":93,
    "old2":87,
    "old1":100,
    "fresh":150
}
```

How would I find the index of "old1" (so, 3) in an object?

How would I go about referencing "old1" by its index if I wanted to set its value?

Answer (score 2):

You should not do this, the order of object properties is not guaranteed.

If you want to use number index, use Array instead.

If you use all string keys (not number format), then most browsers will respect the order of the object expression, but this is not guaranteed.

And if you contain number or number format string as key, then the order won't be the order of the object expression. See:

```
var obj = {
    "expired":93,
    "old3":93,
    "old2":87,
    "old1":100,
    "1": 111,
    "fresh":150
};

for (var key in obj) {
    console.log(key + ' : ' + obj[key]);
}
```

output:

```
1 : 111
expired : 93
old3 : 93
old2 : 87
old1 : 100
fresh : 150
```

Answer (score 0):

For who is still looking for it...I got this solution:

```
<div id="id"></div>
<div id="name"></div>
<div id="age"></div>

var data = {'rows':[
{'id':'1','name':'Andrey','age':'18'},
{'id':'2','name':'Cristine','age':'21'},
{'id':'3','name':'Loren','age':'25'}
]};

$('#id').html(data.rows[0][Object.keys(data.rows[0])[0]]);
$('#name').html(data.rows[0][Object.keys(data.rows[0])[1]]);
$('#age').html(data.rows[0][Object.keys(data.rows[0])[2]]);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/robsonvasconcelos/rr2133h4/)